# VirtualBox Bridged Adapter DHCP works, but no network traffic

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dhcp, bridged

I'm running VirtualBox on macOS where I host a Windows 10 VM guest.

I've been able to establish comms between the guest and the internet through a **NAT** connection.

However, I would like the VM to be registered on the local network, so I'm attempting to set the following **Bridged Adapter** up:

[image: VirtualBox Bridge Adapter Configuration]

The guest is picked up by the DHCP server. Here you can see the IP being assigned dynamically:

[image: VirtualBox Bridge Adapter DHCP]

When I do a `tracert`, the guest was able to resolve the google.com IP, but the ICMP messages are not getting through.

[image: VirtualBox Bridge Adapter Traceroute]

I checked all the firewalls and everything's been turned off. I am actually able to get through to the host machine.

[image: VirtualBox Bridge Adapter ping host]

Any idea how I would be able to get traffic through, would be appreciated.

### Update 1:

I fired up Wireshark on the host to have a look at the packets originating from the guest. I tried a few telnet sessions and also navigating to a website, but it assumed all packets were lost.

I'm not familiar with the NBNS or LLMAR protocols though, but it does not appear as if any packets made it beyond the host.

I then pinged the host again, and one can clearly see the ICMP's there.

[image: VirtualBox Bridged Adapter Network Traffic Lost]

On the guest side, Wireshark picked up a lot of chatter. Not really sure what to make of it.

Comment: How does it look from the host side?  I assume all packets are lost?

Comment: Though VirtualBox somewhat supports bridging Wi-Fi adapters, you really should not. In regular networking, that’s not a supported feature.

Comment: @TrippKinetics: Please see my Update 1 above. It appears as if nothing is getting through.

Comment: @DanielB: I was not aware of this limitation. Thanks.

Comment: @guest-vm: Thanks! Unfortunately the result is the same as above. I need to VPN to a remote site from my guest. (I tried macOS PPTP clients on the host, but there are driver compatibility issues.) The only option that has internet connectivity is NAT, but I've been unable to get that going (either I'm screwing the ports up, or its an issue with the internal IP). Bottom line: I'll do anything to get the VPN up. Naturally, host-only is unfortunately not suited for this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBox's implementation of NAT only supports TCP & UDP among all transport layer protocols[[1]](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nat-limitations), so VPN via PPTP won't work. As support for bridged networking with wireless interfaces is also limited[[2]](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged), you may consider the followings alternative.

**Host-only network with *Internet*** can be achieved with IP routing by host. I've done that before with Windows/Ubuntu host & guests. It should work for Macintosh too.

In OSX host(192.168.8.109), enable ip routing by `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`

In Win10 guest with host-only adapter(192.168.56.10), set default gateway to OSX(192.168.56.1), set DNS to router.

In router(192.168.8.1), add static route via web interface or SSH `route add -net 192.168.56.0/24 gw 192.168.8.109`

Comment: Read this [lab manual](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/cs60/lab3/vm-networking.pdf)(courtesy of CS@Dartmouth) for setting up internet in VBox guest with *Host-only Adapter* and native NAT by MacOS host.